# Flex wrap and overflow on both column and row

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, css-grid

I am trying to create a resizable flex box that can only accommodate as much detail as it could. I want the inner items to be stacked horizontally.

**Flex items should grow horizontally until width and wrap itself:**

[image: Flex should grow row direction]

**When reducing the width, it will wrap to the next line:**

[image]

**But when I resize so that the height is not sufficient, I want the items to over flow completely. Unlike in this image here, it's partially inside.**

[image]

I have written the below for wrapping it for width, how do I do it for height as well?

```
 display: flex;

  flex-direction: row;

  flex-wrap: wrap;

  background-color: green;

  overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: *"I want the items to over flow completely"* What do you mean by that? Do you mean to remove the flex-wrapping completely when container height can't can't contain the elements? Or just like in your image, but instead of hiding the last two element, it would instead overflow visibly?

Comment: yes, in the last image you could see "7" and "8" are half visible.. instead I want them to overflow and I should see empty spaces there (just like how it overflows in row)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a resizable container using the `resize` property then it will not be able to overflow like you want to because it's not compatible with `overflow: visible;`

> The resize property does not apply to inline elements or to block elements where overflow="visible". So, make sure that overflow is set to "scroll", "auto", or "hidden".

```css
.container {
  background: #008000;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 160px;
  resize: both;
  gap: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's a workaround, but some tradeoffs that might not be exactly what you are looking for. Check the snippets:

```css
.container {
  background: #008000;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 120px;
  max-width: 160px;
  resize: vertical;
  gap: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have removed the resize and set the height to some value; say 200px. If I see any content whose bottom > 200px then I want them to overflow to next page. In other words, I want to display only complete boxes.. not partial boxes.

Comment: do you mind if the flex-direction of the elements are changed? and the width of the container fixed?

Comment: Ah well, it's supposed to be the other way... but yeah, I would like to try that.. as long as it's not clipping the content.

Comment: I've added another snippet of a workaround that might not be, but you can check it out.